# Why is my javascript/flask speech recognition code posting the results as None and not appending the input box?

Tags: javascript, python, html, speech-recognition

I have a flask app that uses js speech recognition to append user's answers to an HTML input box. The inputs are then sent and appended to the next page's list. Currently, the list is appended "None" and there are no errors in the console. I've been using [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-speech-recognition-and-speech-synthesis-in-javascript-9bcb213f6ddd) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eIRrowvLRk) to no avail and also have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68138455/why-is-my-speech-recognition-on-js-not-working) and [this](https://gist.github.com/strongSoda/27f4caf1335e3d03accf708e1fcdcbf0)

Here's the Main.py code:

```
from flask import render_template, Flask, request
import os
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer as SIA
import nltk
import io
import os
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = 'static')

# # set the stopwords to be the english version
# stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
# # vader sentiment analyzer for analyzing the sentiment of the text
# sid = SIA()
# # patient.name?


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    user = request.values.get('name')
    location = request.values.get('location')
    state = request.values.get('state')
    # if request.method == "POST":
        # with mic as source:
        #     holder = []
        #     for x in info:
        #         audio_data = r.listen(source)
        #         r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        #         text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language = 'en-IN')
        #         holder.append(text.lower())
        #         if x == "state":
        #             ss = sid.polarity_scores(holder)
        #             if ss == "neg":
        #                 x.append(str("sad"))
        #             else:
        #                 x.append(str("not sad"))
        #         else:
        #             filtered_words = [words for words in holder if not words in stop_words] # this filters out the stopwords
        #             x.append(filtered_words.lower())

        # return redirect(url_for('care', user = user))

    return render_template('index.html', user = user, location=location, state=state)

@app.route("/care", methods=["POST"])
def care():
    user = request.values.get('name')
    location = request.values.get('location')
    state = request.values.get('state')
    return render_template('list.html', user = user, location=location, state=state)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #app.run(debug=True)    
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!---------Therapist Section--------->
    <section id="therapist">
        <div class="container" id="therapist_container">
            <div id="button">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="record" id="therapist-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Talk with Delphi</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="vid1Title" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <video width="100%" id="video1">
                      <source src="./static/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    <form class="texts" action="/care" id="careid" name="care" method="POST">
                      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="what's your name?">
                      <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Where are you?">
                      <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="how can I help?">
                      <input id="buttonInput" class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
              $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                  $('#video1')[0].play();
                })
              $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                  $('#video1')[0].pause();
                })

              video = document.getElementById('video1');

              // window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;              

              function record() {
                  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || SpeechRecognition();
                  recognition.interimResults = true;
                  recognition.lang = "en-US";
 
                  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                      console.log(event);
                      document.getElementById("name").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                  }
                  recognition.start();

                  recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                    recognition.start
                    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                      // console.log(event);
                      document.getElementById("location").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                  }
                  })

                  recognition.addEventListener("end", () =>{
                    recognition.start
                    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                      // console.log(event);
                      document.getElementById("state").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                    }
                    recognition.addEventListener("end", () => {
                      window.location.pathname = '/care';
                      document.care.submit();
                    });
                  })
                }              
              // video.addEventListener('ended',function(){       
              //    window.location.pathname = '/care';
              //    document.care.submit();
              // })
            </script>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock content %}
```

List.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!----LIST------>
<section id="care_list">
    <div class="container" id="care_list_container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron text-center" id="care_list_title">{{ user }} Care Record</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-hover"> 
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Session #</th>
                    <th scope="col">Length</th>
                    <th scope="col">Location</th>
                    <th scope="col">State</th> 
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>{{ length }}</td>
                    <td>{{ location }}</td>
                    <td>{{ state }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="care_list">
            <li class="list-group-item">Please email tom@vrifyhealth.com for help.</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</section> 
{% endblock content %}
```

Here's the screenshot of the output and the console:[image: Console and output page. None should be replaced by the text in the input boxes]